# lookup value in a non-standard table

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to use VLOOKUP-like functionality on a table that I have which unfortunately doesn't have the layout that is standard for VLOOKUP function.
Layout is as below:

```
                 Dealership 1    |        Dealership 2    |      Dealership 3

Make    | Discount 1 | Website 1 | Discount 2 | Website 2 | Discount 3 | Website 3
Hyundai | 20%        |     www1  |     30%    |    www3   |     10%    |   www4
BMW     | 10%        |     www1  |     15%    |    www3   |     3%     |   www4
Honda   | 20%        |     www1  |     50%    |    www3   |     70%    |   www4
```

So Normally would I would do is VLOOKUP the whole array for rows that match the make I am looking for and output the discount I am looking for. However, I want to specify which Dealership I am getting the discount from as well.

Comment: How is the Dealership cell formatted? Is it a merged cell?

Comment: @ScottCraner merged, yes

Comment: This is possible is you know how to use nested formulas with IF and VLOOKUP.

Comment: Can you possibly create a helper row? In a row above (or below) "Dealership #", add the dealership number in each column (can format text to white so it doesn't show).  That might be the quickest way, and you can then use [`Index/Match`](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/) to return what you want I believe.

Comment: upvoted the question mainly because you supplied some nice sample data! but also for the explanation and pointing out what you tried.

Answer (score 5):

You would use the MATCH as your third Criterion:

```
=VLOOKUP(I2,$A:$G,MATCH(J2,$1:$1,0),FALSE)
```

[image]

The MATCH() returns the column in which the Dealership is found.  And uses that in the VLOOKUP to denote in which column the discount is found.

Comment: oh crap, scoot is back from the weekend obligations and is awake.  He is just getting warmed up though, or he may have turn I2 and J2 into drop down boxes and possibly supplied the website in L2.  (things that were totally not asked for)

Comment: @ForwardEd only my mom calls me `scoot` :) And to get the website: `=VLOOKUP(I2,$A:$G,MATCH(J2,$1:$1,0)+1,FALSE)`

Comment: Not sure which part of the formula extracts the actual discount?

Comment: @EduardKim the MATCH returns the correct column and the VLOOKUP itself provide the correct row.

Comment: I would have limited the range of the match instead of being the entire first row $1:$1 to being the range over the table, $A$1:$G$1  just in case some random text does not bugger stuff up in row 1 way off to the right.  Same goes for the A:G, I would have specified just the table.  @ScottCraner  Does this solution only work because the table is in the top left corner?

Comment: The full row and full column references do not add calculation times, and since I am looking for exact matches means that it would need to get passed the table before looking outside.  Yes there would need to be some adjustments to the MATCH() Function if the table does not start in Column A.  For example IF it was in B:H then using the column range makes sence to use instead of full row reference. `=VLOOKUP(I2,B:H,MATCH(J2,B1:H1,0),FALSE)`  But I am lazy and usually find the route that returns what I want with the least amount of typing. @ForwardEd

Comment: I have to upvote the answer now that I accidently impersonated Scott's Mom!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `INDEX` and `MATCH` combination to get a value in a 2D range

[image]

The formula I used here was

```
=INDEX($B$2:$G$4,MATCH($B$7,$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH("Discount "&$B$8,$B$1:$G$1,0))
```